# xslt unwrap only the first para element in an entry element

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Some entry elements in a Dita table are formatted incorrectly:

```
<entry><p>Description</p></entry>
<entry><p>Description2</p><p>Description3</p><p>Description4</p>
```

If there is only one `<p>` element in a `<entry>` element I want to unwrap/remove the `<p>` element, just leaving the text. If there are more than 1 `<p>` elements in an `<entry>` element, I want to upwrap/remove just the first one. I want to leave all the other elements in the file the same.

So the output would look like:

```
<entry>Description</entry>
<entry>Description2<p>Description3</p><p>Description4</p>
```

I know this is easy but I haven't used my xslt skills in over seven years and am trying to help someone.

All help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <entry><p>Description</p></entry>
    <entry><p>Description2</p><p>Description3</p><p>Description4</p></entry>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry/p[1]"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <entry>Description</entry>
    <entry>Description2<p>Description3</p><p>Description4</p></entry>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think this will do the trick!!!